# One javascript function from multiple html buttons

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Weird question but I have a javascript function that draws on a canvas. I created buttons on HTML that uses that function. I have multiple buttons with different image sources that I want to use for that one function without having repeat the function many times and just change the imgsrc. I tried giving the button ids but you shouldn't have multiple ids. I tried using classes but it didn't seem to work. Using AngularJS.

HTML

```
<md-button onclick="(new avatarCanvas()).body()" style="border: 3px solid black;"><input class="image" value="www.website.com/image1.png" type="hidden"></md-button>

<md-button onclick="(new avatarCanvas()).hair()" style="border: 3px solid black;"><input class="hair" value="www.website.com/image2.png" type="hidden"></md-button> 

<md-button onclick="(new avatarCanvas()).hair()" style="border: 3px solid black;"><input class="hair" value="www.website.com/image3.png" type="hidden"></md-button>

<md-button onclick="(new avatarCanvas()).hair()" style="border: 3px solid black;"><input class="hair" value="www.website.com/image4.png" type="hidden"></md-button>

<md-button onclick="(new avatarCanvas()).hair()" style="border: 3px solid black;"><input class="hair" value="www.website.com/image5.png" type="hidden"></md-button>
```

JavaScript

```
var canvas1 = document.getElementById('layer1');
var ctx1 = canvas1.getContext('2d');

var canvas2 = document.getElementById('layer2');
var ctx2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');

var imageObj = new Image();

this.body = function() { 
imageObj.onload = function() {
  ctx1.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0, imageObj.width, imageObj.height);
};
imageObj.src = document.getElementsByClassName("image").value;
}

this.hair = function() {
ctx2.clearRect(0, 0, canvas2.width, canvas2.height);
imageObj.onload = function() {
  ctx2.drawImage(imageObj, 64.43, 7, imageObj.width, imageObj.height);
 };
imageObj.src = document.getElementsByClassName("hair").value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to you to create custom directive on button to handle the click event as it is repeated task. And you can add custom attributes like "data-img-path" rather using hidden variable to pass the image path.

eg:

```
<md-button data-load-avatar style="border: 3px solid black;" data-image-path="www.website.com/image1.png"  />
```

here "data-load-avatar" is a custom directive where you can add click event and read the attribute "data-image-path" and use this image path in load that in canvas. This way you code will be clean and maintainable as well.

Comment: Okay so when using these custom directives, how do I call them back in my javascript function?

Comment: in the directive you can add click event and read the image path and load it.